# Can we open new window along with stylesheet,javascript and jquery refrence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I open a new window with a image.Here is code

```
var image = new image();
image = document.getElementById("img").src;  // src is base64
image.style.width = "700px";
var w= window.open("");

w.document.write(image.outerHtml);
```

It works fine for me. If i inspect element then i see the only "img" tag with base64 src;

If i make HTML markup along with JS,jquery and CSS references  do like this below

```
var markup = "<script> // reference </script> "  // place all jquery and java script references 

markup = markup +"<style>"//references +</style>

markup = //all markup like <img> tag

w.document.write(markup);
```

My question is that are all references of JS,CSS and Jquery will work or not?

I am using ASP.net mvc 5.(FYI)

Comment: Would probably work if all your css and js paths are absolute including your full domain. Relative paths, not sure, but you could try.

Comment: The URL is about:blank. It means its another separate i think. But i think i should try